# how to validate user input date with system current date in java while using datechooser in an issue class

Tags: java, date, validation, jdatechooser, jcalendar

```
package librarymanagementsystem;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;


public class IssueBook extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JPanel contentPane;
    JDateChooser dateChooser;
    private JTextField t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14;
    private JButton b1,b2,b3,b4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new IssueBook().setVisible(true);
            
    }

    public IssueBook() {
        setBounds(300, 200, 900, 500);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Book_id");
    l1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l1.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l1.setBounds(47, 63, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l1);

    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Name");
    l2.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l2.setBounds(47, 97, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l2);

    JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Author");
    l3.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l3.setBounds(47, 131, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l3);

    JLabel l4 = new JLabel("Publisher");
    l4.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l4.setBounds(47, 165, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l4);

    JLabel l5 = new JLabel("Edition");
    l5.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l5.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l5.setBounds(47, 199, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l5);

    JLabel l6 = new JLabel("Price");
    l6.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l6.setBounds(47, 233, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l6);

    JLabel l7 = new JLabel("Pages");
    l7.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l7.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l7.setBounds(47, 267, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l7);

    t1 = new JTextField();
    t1.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t1.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t1.setBounds(126, 66, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(t1);
    
    b1 = new JButton("Search");
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(192, 192, 192), 1, true));
        b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    b1.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    b1.setBounds(234, 59, 100, 30);
        
    contentPane.add(b1);

    t2 = new JTextField();
    t2.setEditable(false);
    t2.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t2.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t2.setBounds(126, 100, 208, 20);
    contentPane.add(t2);
    t2.setColumns(10);

    t3 = new JTextField();
    t3.setEditable(false);
    t3.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t3.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t3.setColumns(10);
    t3.setBounds(126, 131, 208, 20);
    contentPane.add(t3);

    t4 = new JTextField();
    t4.setEditable(false);
    t4.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t4.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t4.setColumns(10);
    t4.setBounds(126, 168, 208, 20);
    contentPane.add(t4);

    t5 = new JTextField();
    t5.setEditable(false);
    t5.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t5.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t5.setColumns(10);
    t5.setBounds(126, 202, 208, 20);
    contentPane.add(t5);

    t6 = new JTextField();
    t6.setEditable(false);
    t6.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t6.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t6.setColumns(10);
    t6.setBounds(126, 236, 208, 20);
    contentPane.add(t6);

    t7 = new JTextField();
    t7.setEditable(false);
    t7.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t7.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t7.setColumns(10);
    t7.setBounds(126, 270, 208, 20);
    contentPane.add(t7);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(47, 79, 79), 2, true), "Issue-Book",
                TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(34, 139, 34)));
    panel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    panel.setBounds(10, 38, 345, 288);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.add(panel);

    JLabel l8 = new JLabel("Student_id");
    l8.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l8.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l8.setBounds(384, 63, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l8);

    JLabel l9 = new JLabel("Name");
    l9.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l9.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l9.setBounds(384, 103, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l9);

    JLabel l10 = new JLabel("Father's Name");
    l10.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l10.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l10.setBounds(384, 147, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l10);

    JLabel l11 = new JLabel("Course");
    l11.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l11.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l11.setBounds(384, 187, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l11);

    JLabel l12 = new JLabel("Branch");
    l12.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l12.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l12.setBounds(384, 233, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l12);

    JLabel l13 = new JLabel("Year");
    l13.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l13.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l13.setBounds(384, 284, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l13);

    JLabel l14 = new JLabel("Semester");
    l14.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    l14.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    l14.setBounds(384, 336, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(l14);

    t8 = new JTextField();
    t8.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t8.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t8.setColumns(10);
    t8.setBounds(508, 66, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(t8);

    b2 = new JButton("Search");
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b2.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    b2.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(192, 192, 192), 1, true));
    b2.setBounds(604, 59, 100, 30);
        b2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.add(b2);

    t9 = new JTextField();
    t9.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t9.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t9.setEditable(false);
    t9.setColumns(10);
    t9.setBounds(508, 106, 208, 20);
    contentPane.add(t9);

    t10 = new JTextField();
    t10.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t10.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t10.setEditable(false);
    t10.setColumns(10);
    t10.setBounds(508, 150, 208, 20);
    contentPane.add(t10);

    t11 = new JTextField();
    t11.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t11.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t11.setEditable(false);
    t11.setColumns(10);
    t11.setBounds(508, 190, 208, 20);
    contentPane.add(t11);

    t12 = new JTextField();
    t12.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t12.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t12.setEditable(false);
    t12.setColumns(10);
    t12.setBounds(508, 236, 208, 20);
    contentPane.add(t12);

    t13 = new JTextField();
    t13.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t13.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t13.setEditable(false);
    t13.setColumns(10);
    t13.setBounds(508, 286, 208, 20);
    contentPane.add(t13);

    t14 = new JTextField();
    t14.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
    t14.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    t14.setEditable(false);
    t14.setColumns(10);
    t14.setBounds(508, 338, 208, 20);
    contentPane.add(t14);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(70, 130, 180), 2, true), "StudentDetails",TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(100, 149, 237)));
    panel_1.setForeground(new Color(0, 100, 0));
    panel_1.setBounds(360, 38, 378, 372);
        panel_1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.add(panel_1);
        
    JLabel l15 = new JLabel(" Date of Issue :");
    l15.setForeground(new Color(105, 105, 105));
    l15.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 15));
    l15.setBounds(20, 340, 118, 26);
    contentPane.add(l15);

    dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
    dateChooser.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
    dateChooser.setForeground(new Color(105, 105, 105));
    dateChooser.setBounds(137, 337, 200, 29);
    contentPane.add(dateChooser);
        

    b3 = new JButton("Issue");
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    b3.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    b3.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(192, 192, 192), 1, true));
    b3.setBounds(47, 377, 118, 33);
    b3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.add(b3);

    b4 = new JButton("Back");
    b4.addActionListener(this);
    b4.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
    b4.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(192, 192, 192), 1, true));
    b4.setBounds(199, 377, 100, 33);
    b4.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.add(b4);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        try{
            conn con = new conn();
            if(ae.getSource() == b1){
                String sql = "select * from book where book_id = ?";
        PreparedStatement st = con.c.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, t1.getText());
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        
                while (rs.next()) {
                    t2.setText(rs.getString("name"));
                    t3.setText(rs.getString("author"));
                    t4.setText(rs.getString("publisher"));
                    t5.setText(rs.getString("edition"));
                    t6.setText(rs.getString("price"));
                    t7.setText(rs.getString("pages"));
        }
        st.close();
        rs.close();
        
            }
            if(ae.getSource() == b2){
                String sql = "select * from student where student_id = ?";
        PreparedStatement st = con.c.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, t8.getText());
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        
                while (rs.next()) {
                    t9.setText(rs.getString("name"));
                    t10.setText(rs.getString("father"));
                    t11.setText(rs.getString("course"));
                    t12.setText(rs.getString("branch"));
                    t13.setText(rs.getString("year"));
                    t14.setText(rs.getString("semester"));
        }
        st.close();
        rs.close();
        
            }
            if(ae.getSource() == b3){
                    try{
                String sql = "insert into issuebook(book_id, student_id, bname, sname, course, branch, dateOfIssue) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement st = con.c.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, t1.getText());
        st.setString(2, t8.getText());
        st.setString(3, t2.getText());
        st.setString(4, t9.getText());
        st.setString(5, t11.getText());
        st.setString(6, t12.getText());
        st.setString(7, ((JTextField) dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()); 
                               
                
        int i = st.executeUpdate();
        if (i > 0)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Book Issued..!");
        else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                                }
            }
            if(ae.getSource() == b4){
                this.setVisible(false);
        new Home().setVisible(true);
            
            }
            
            con.c.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            
        }
    }
}
```

*this is the code for issuing book. I want to validate the user input date of issuing book with the system current date.
I want to validate

```
st.setString(7, ((JTextField) dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
```

I have tried using date functions like `now()` but unable to fix it.
how can I get the results?

Comment: It is more helpful if you can give a minimal example of your current approach instead of your entire file.

Comment: You should also look at `javax.swing.InputVerifier`.